# Thread-safe resetting of an object's reference

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, thread-safety

The **someParameters** hashmap is loaded from a .csv file every twenty minutes or so by one thread and set by the **setParameters** method.

It is very frequently read by multiple threads calling **getParameters**: to perform a lookup translation of one value into a corresponding value.

Is the code unsafe and/ or the "wrong" way to achieve this (particularly in terms of performance)? I know about ConcurrentHashMap but am trying to get a more fundamental understanding of concurrency, rather than using classes that are inherrently thread-safe.

One potential risk I see is that the object reference **someParameters** could be reset whilst another thread is reading the copy, so the other thread might not have the latest values (which wouldn't matter to me).

```
public class ConfigObject {
    private static HashMap<String, String> someParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getParameters(){
        return new HashMap<String, String>(someParameters);
        //to some thread which will only ever iterate or get
    }

    public void setParameters(HashMap<String, String> newParameters){
        //could be called by any thread at any time
        someParameters = newParameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: creating a whole new hashmap to return from getParameters is a really expensive solution. A better one would be to use Collections.unmodifiableMap

Comment: Assignment is an atomic operator, so there are no threading issues here

Comment: @ControlAltDel Threading **is** an issue here: It's all about visibility, not atomicity (in this case)! The field must be published properly to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here

1. Visibility problem, as `someParameters` after update might not be visible to other thread, to fix this mark `someParameters` as `volatile`.
2. Other problem is performance one due to creating new HashMap in get method, to fix that use Utility method `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` this just wrap original map and disallowing put/remove method.

Comment: You have valid concern, but Original poster not updating original map, he want to create new one every time from csv file and it this case there is no need for thread-safe map.

Comment: You are right. Instead of creating a new map for every get request, an unmodifiable map is a solution. I thought you want to solve the (concurrent) writing part by directly writing into the original map and returning a unmodifiable map in the get method. Removed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to change/replace many parameters at once (atomically). Unfortunately, `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't support atomic bulk inserts/updates.

To achieve this, you should use shared `ReadWriteLock`. Advantage comparing to `Collections.synchronized...` is that *concurrent reads can be performed simultaneously*: if `readLock` is acquired from some thread, `readLock().lock()` called from another thread will not block.

```
ReadWriteLock lock = new ReadWriteLock();

// on write:
lock.writeLock().lock();
try {
   // write/update operation, 
   // e. g. clear map and write new values
} finally {
   lock.writeLock().unlock();
}

// on read:
lock.readLock().lock();
try {
   // read operation
} finally {
   lock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this block `get()` while doing write? I think creating new map and replacing reference better approach in this case with use of volatile to safely publish.

Comment: @kr.pradeep of course it will, that's purpose of write lock. OP asked for alternative solutions, one of which I provided. Problem of replacing a collection is that other threads can continue work with old data even after actual collection was updated. I don't know exactly OP's purposes and restrictions: maybe it is allowable, maybe not.

Comment: Don't use that complex locking strategy, if a simple `synchronzed` or `volatile` field may do! We don't know if performance is that important here. Apart from that, I still consider `ConcurrentHashMap` an option, if there are no invariants across multiple map entries. In that case, there is not need to have one single atomic bulk update.

Comment: @isnot2bad I repeat: OP asked for alternative solution, I provided. And I don't see anything *complex* here.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Maybe I used the wrong words: Not complex (because easy to read and understand), but not necessary in my point of view. I think, the OP should try the most simple solution and only optimize the code if measurements show that it is necessary. And the most simple solution might be a simple `volatile` field.

Comment: @isnot2bad I believe OP will decide by himself =) He has so many options here, every of which has pros and cons.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I agree, but as the OP seems to be a beginner concerning concurrency, we should guide him to the basics first.